# Cake Clean task is skipped on cake build

Tags: .net-core, cakebuild

Brand-new Cake project, `build.cake` written as in [Setting Up A New Project](https://cakebuild.net/docs/getting-started/setting-up-a-new-project), added to a `net5.0` console application.

When running `dotnet cake`, the task Clean is silently skipped by runner.

I ran `dotnet cake --target="Clean" --verbosity=normal` and received this:

`Error: One or more errors occurred. (Could not reach target 'Clean' since it was skipped due to a criteria.)`

No idea what criteria is skipping the task.

My `build.cake`:

```
var target = Argument("target", "Test");
var configuration = Argument("configuration", "Release");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TASKS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Task("Clean")
.WithCriteria(c => HasArgument("rebuild"))
.Does(() => 
{
    CleanDirectory($"./LucroMei/bin/{configuration}");
});

Task("Build")
.IsDependentOn("Clean")
.Does(() => 
{
    DotNetCoreBuild("./LucroMei.sln", new DotNetCoreBuildSettings
    {
        Configuration = configuration,
    });
});

Task("Test")
.IsDependentOn("Build")
.Does(() => 
{
    DotNetCoreTest("./LucroMei.sln", new DotNetCoreTestSettings
    {
        Configuration = configuration,
        NoBuild = true,
    });
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// EXECUTION
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

RunTarget(target);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Clean` task in your script is defined with [criteria](https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/tasks/criteria), take a look at this line:

```
.WithCriteria(c => HasArgument("rebuild"))
```

It means that the task will run only in case the condition is specified. The condition is [`HasArgument("rebuild")`](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common/ArgumentAliases/20DF3649), which is trying to find the argument named `rebuild` among other arguments specified.

If you run your script like this, the Clean target will run:

```
dotnet cake --rebuild
```

Comment: And it works \o/ From what I understand, I can pass the --rebuild flag as an Argument variable to the runner, after deleting the .HasCriteria line, right? This is finally making sense.

Comment: If you delete `WithCriteria` line for a task, it won't be constrained by any conditions. And yes, you can add `rebuild` wtih the `Argument` alias as well.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is very clear:

> Could not reach target 'Clean' since it was **skipped due to a criteria**

Looking at your `Clean` target, it has a criteria expectation:

```
Task("Clean")
.WithCriteria(c => HasArgument("rebuild")) // <<#<<#<<#<<#<<#<<#####
.Does(() => { ... });
```

This means that your `Clean` criteria will only run if you provide the argument `--rebuild`:

```
dotnet cake --target="Clean" --verbosity=normal --rebuild
```